# Round all numbers in the string

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've got formula strings like:

`let a = '554898128.3227372 + (-1.35880 * (A * 12)) + (1.1171758319197438 * (B * 13)) + (0.8813173184360715 * (x + 1))';`

or

`let b = '10867.306445101707 + (1.6367961676820935 * (X + 1))';`

I want to round numbers in the formula to three decimals. What's the fastest way to do that? I thought about using `a.split(' ');` to split my string to array and checking if it's number, but what do I do about the round brackets? The formula has to remain the same just with rounded values afterwards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A crude way to do that would be to extract everything that looks like a number and apply `toFixed`.

```js
let a = '554898128.3227372 + (-1.35880 * (A * 12)) + (1.1171758319197438 * (B * 13)) + (0.8813173184360715 * (x + 1))';

a = a.replace(/-?\d+(\.\d+)?/g, n => Number(n).toFixed(3))

console.log(a)
```

A better, but far more complicated, option is to parse the string and replace the numbers in the parse tree. Since I presume you're going to need this anyways, to evaluate the formula, this might be actually the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a regular expression to match numeric characters with decimals, capturing everything up to the first 3 decimals, and replace with that captured group:

```js
let a = '554898128.3227372 + (-1.35880 * (A * 12)) + (1.1171758319197438 * (B * 13)) + (0.8813173184360715 * (x + 1))';

console.log(
  a.replace(/(\d+\.\d{3})\d+/g, '$1')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Split won't do a trick cause you'll have to handle all those non-numeric symbols and putting them back together.
Generic way of handling formulas is writing lexical analyzer or using some 3rd party for that.
Luckily here, you might just use [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method with regex that matches any number with period like this:

```js
const a = '554898128.3227372 + (-1.35880 * (A * 12)) + (1.1171758319197438 * (B * 13)) + (0.8813173184360715 * (x + 1))';

const b = a.replace(/\d+\.\d+/g, function(n) {
    return Math.round(Number(n));
});

console.log(b);
```